# SQL Server: Storing Query Result into Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to Concatenate Query Result for each Person into a Variable.
Cursor Extract Columname from #temp table and extract data from PersonTable

For Example:For PID=1(FName: John LName:Hill HomeCountry=US HomeState=CH)
123JohnHillUSCH

```
  Person Table:

pid FName   LName   HomeCity    HomeState
1   Pascal    E    New York      NY
2   Steve     F    New York      NY

CREATE table #Temp
    ([Id] int,  [ColumnName] varchar(13))
;

INSERT INTO #Temp
    ([Id],[ColumnName])
VALUES
    (1,  'EID'),
    (2,  'FName'),
    (3,  'LName'),
    (4,  'HomeCountry'),
    (5,  'HomeState')
;

SELECT * FROM #Temp



SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_Conv_GenerateResultsFromMappingTable]
@Param1 VARCHAR(30)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Cur as CURSOR;

SET @Cur = CURSOR FOR
SELECT columnName FROM #Temp

OPEN @Cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @ColName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX)
PRINT @Param1;
SET @Query='SELECT '+@ColName+' FROM dbo.PERSON where PID='+@Param1+''  
PRINT @Query 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
                  ,  N'@Param1 varchar(30)', 
                   @Param1 


FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @ColName;
END

CLOSE @Cur;
DEALLOCATE @Cur;
```

Expected result

```
1,1PascalENewYorkNY
2,2SteveFNewYorkNY
```

Comment: Are those columns you want to concatenate all in the same table? Or are they stored the way you show in your example, row by row?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected results from the PERSON  table

Comment: @RyanWilson: Yes but Row Wise for Each Employee..For Example: Output Table Contains EID, Concat(EID,FName,LName,HomeState,HomeCity),CreatedOn

Comment: @SQLLearner I think you got your answer below.

Comment: @scsimon: Added Person & Output Table

Comment: Using a cursor is completely the wrong way to go here. Looping should be avoided with the exception of a few administrative things. I am not quite understanding the desired output here.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+, Why not just do

```
SELECT EID, CONCAT(EID, FName, LName, HomeCountry, HomeState) AS ConcatString, CreateDate
FROM Person
```

In SQL Server 2008R2 and below, it would have to be

```
SELECT EID, CAST(EID AS VARCHAR(20) + FName + LName + HomeCountry + HomeState AS ConcatString, CreateDate
FROM Person
```

And if You're wanting to return the results per user, you could parameterize it, and send in the EID individually from the source, or you *could* use a cursor...if you have absolutely no other option. If you're wanting to return the entire dataset, You can just consume the data straight from that dataset.

Comment: Great answer. Make sure when you use varchar that you ALWAYS specifiy the size. The defaults can change depending on usage. As with everything always better to be explicit. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Yeah I got lazy on that one. I went ahead and just changed it to the max allowable length for a bigint.